# how to make a clone of a column js?

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

HTMl

```
<table>
<tr class="tab">
<td class="one">3</td>
<td class="one">4</td>
<td id="shes">5</td>
<td class="shee">6</td>
<td class="five">7</td>
<td class="six">8</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

js

```
  let elem = document.querySelectorAll('td.one');
  elem.forEach((el) => {
  el.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', "<td>clone td.one(number)</td>");
           });
```

how to clone column information ".one"

I tried using cloneNode but how to do it in .forEach don't understand

Comment: How is your solution not working? what's the expected result compared to the actual result?

Comment: I need to create a copy of the td data that foreach creates.

Comment: I'm not quite following; you need a clone of the adjacentHTML that was already inserted? Your code is already inserting a `<td>` after each `td.one`. Do you need two new `<td>`s inserted?

Comment: I insert what I can. And it is necessary to insert a clone of td.one. The output is the same only the information from td.one

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) for `node.cloneNode()`? Please show your attempt with this method.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `tr > td:nth-child(…)` where `…` is the number of the column to copy. Then use [Element.after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/after) which offers a straightforward way to insert adjacent elements -

```js
const col2 = document.querySelectorAll("tr > td:nth-child(2)")

for (const td of col2)
  td.after(td.cloneNode(true))
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>d</td>
    <td>e</td>
    <td>f</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: is it possible to clone in this place  " el.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', "<td>clone td.one(number)</td>" ?